# JQuery slide down text with float right image

Tags: jquery, html, css-float, slidedown

The overflow is hidden of a text it doesn't flow around a floated right image.

If you slide down the text will go down in one block and ignores the floated image. If slideDown is ready the text goes around the image. That is the wanted behaviour.

I already tried to change overflow:hidden to overflow-y:hidden but this doesn't change anything. Also display:inline-block doesn't work.

html:

```
<div>
<div class="image" style="float:right;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
</div>
<div class="slideDown">slide down</div>
<p style="display:none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){

  $(".slideDown").bind('click',function(e){

     $('p').slideToggle();

  });
```

})

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wzh2x/ fiddle example link

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML didn't do what you wanted it to because `div` and `p` are block elements and so text don't wrap around them.
So inoder to wrap text you have to force `p` to act `inline`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zA5VD/2/)**

#### CSS

```
div {
    float:left;
}
img {
    float:right;
}
p {
    clear:left;
}
.slideDown {
    float:left;
}
```

#### html

```
<div> <span class="slideDown">slideDown</span>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
    <p style="display:none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
 aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
 pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here are dirty workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/Wzh2x/2/ ...

```
$(function(){

    $.fn.mySlide = function ( speed ) {

        var $self = $(this),
            $p = $self.find('p'),
            h = $p.height(),
            speed = speed || 650;



        $p.css({marginTop: -h});

        $self.find('.slideDown').bind('click',function(e){

            $this_p = $(this).next('p');
            h = h === 0?-$this_p.height():0; 
            $this_p.animate({marginTop: h}, speed);

        });        

        return this;
    };

    $('.test').mySlide(500);    

})
```